# How to prevent 'make clean' from building files scheduled for removal

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I run make clean twice the second invocation will build the dependency Makefiles that are scheduled for removal. How can I get Makefile to recognize the files scheduled for removal and skip the recursive call to make for that directory? In other words, only make clean in sub directory if the makefile already exists in each sub directory, on a per sub directory basis. I don't know the GNU-Make syntax but I'm looking for something like:

```
Dependencies=[dependency1,dependency2,dependency3,dependency4]
DoNotMake=[bool1,bool2,bool3,bool4]
for all (i < 4): 
    if (! Dependencies(i)/Makefile):
        DoNotMake(i)=true
```

The current rules for make clean are as follows:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(MAKE) MAKEDEPEND=off SUBDIR_ARGS=clean
    rm -f dependency1/Makefile
    rm -f dependency2/Makefile
    rm -f dependency3/Makefile
    rm -f dependency4/Makefile
    rm -f dependency4/src/config.h.in
```

Comment: Other parts of the Makefile are being invoked via the recursive `$(MAKE)` invocation. We cannot analyze what happens there because you have not posted those parts of the Makefile code.

Comment: Do you want *consistency*, or do you want to *not build files*? Why is that `$(MAKE)` in the recipe, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @tripleee: I was looking for the dependency makefiles in response to your question and found that they weren't present, a big clue for me (Duh, running 'make clean' explicitly removes them!) The 2nd half of the puzzle was solved by your statement that dependency makefiles are being invoked via $(MAKE). Thus the 2nd call to 'make clean' must build the makefiles to run the recursive call before they can be removed!

Comment: The question is now: how can I prevent 'make clean' from building the very makefiles that will later be removed?

Comment: Without your code to look at, what more can we say than "don't do that then"?

Comment: Could you elucidate which code would be more helpful? To my understanding, the above is all that pertains to 'make clean' command. Nothing in the dependency makefiles should be relevant since were trying to circumvent them in the case that their not built. Everything else in the source makefile governs other calls such as mode=debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you a definite answer since there's still a lot of your makefile that you haven't posted, but here are some things that we do to solve similar problems.

The make variable `MAKECMDGOALS` contains the current make target.  If you want to avoid doing something when you run `make clean`, you can do something like this:

```
ifeq (,$(findstring $(MAKECMDGOALS),clean))
  # Whatever you place here won't be run when you run 'make clean'
endif
```

You can also add a bit of shell script to only invoke a sub-makefile when it exists:

```
some_target:
    [ -f $(SUB_FOLDER)/Makefile ] && $(MAKE) -C $(SUB_FOLDER)
```

If your makefiles are being created implicitly, then these may not work.  You may be able to use the `--assume-old=` option to prevent make from re-building the makefiles (I've never tried to use that on a file that doesn't exist, so YMMV).